# Invalid op code from truffle console

Tags: contract-development, truffle, invalid-opcode

I'm following this tutorial for a simple contract.
https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-smart-contracts-in-ethereum-848f08001f05

After running testrpc, compiled with truffle compile and deploy with migrate, I open the truffle console and run these commands:

```
truffle(default)> var poe = ProofOfExistence1.at(ProofOfExistence1.address)
// and print its address 

truffle(default)> poe.address
0x3d3bce79cccc331e9e095e8985def13651a86004

// let's register our first "document"
truffle(default)> poe.notarize('An amazing idea')
```

but when I run this last command, instead of obtaining the output described there I get an error:

```
truffle(development)> poe.notarize('An amazing idea')
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:1
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:38:1)
```

I tried to repeat all the procedure very carefully but got the same error. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you are using an old version of `ethereumjs-testrpc` now the equivalent project is `ganache-cli`.

Comment: thank you very much! after installing it everything worked. Many Thanks!